# Which data model for storing a month and year?

Tags: django, django-models, model

I need to create a model which has a production month and year.

I can see 2 possibilities here:

- Use a `DateField`, with the `day` set to 1, and only use the month and date
- Use 2 `IntegerFields`, one for the month and the other for the year.

What are the advantages of each solution? Which do you recommend and why? Are there any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date field with a day set to 1 would be a better option. If you don't need a day it's not critical, it's just a date formatting problem when displaying end result to a user, like displaying a month as May instead of 05. You can use dates with day 01 in all sql queries as you normally would (filtering, grouping, sorting, etc).

To make the choice more obvious let me ask in return what would be the best way to store time if I didn't care about seconds - as a time field with seconds set to 0, or as hours and minutes in two separated integers.

Storing it as a date comes with free benefits: date validation, date functions, date ordering, date formatting.